# Access Violation passing QString to slot

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

This is similar to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675051/buffer-overrun-using-qt-threads-and-signals) I posted yesterday  but I was able to further isolate the problem so I rather ask a new one.

I have a QThread that emits a signal and passes a QString to a slot. 
This is how I connect signal and slot:

```
connect(reader, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this, SLOT(threadError(QString)))
```

This is how a signal is emitted:

```
void Reader::read() {
    emit error("No new data for 500 samples");
    while (1) {
    }
}
```

This is the slot implementation:

```
void MainWindow::threadError(const QString msg) {
    std::string st = msg.toStdString();
    int i = 0; //never reached
}
```

Accessing the msg QString causes an access violation exception even if the thread keeps on running. I looked at many examples and I couldn't find a different way to do it. What am I doing wrong?

Update: 
Declaration:

```
class Reader : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Reader();
    ~Reader();

    public slots:
    void read();

signals:
    void error(QString err);
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent, const std::string &config_file, const 
    ~MainWindow();

    private slots:
    void threadError(QString msg);
}
```

Comment: `const QString msg` did you mean `const QString &msg` ?

Comment: @Ilya No. Should I pass the QString by reference?

Comment: I'd pass it by value, just `QString msg`

Comment: How is your `error` signal defined?

Comment: @Ilya unfortunately no luck

Comment: @VictorPolevoy void error(QString err);

Comment: Are you sure your thread is alive after emitting `error`? If there is not a direct connection I think you may emit it without effect.

Comment: `emit error(QString("No new data for 500 samples"));` ?

Comment: @Ilya tried that as well. No luck either

Comment: @Ilya is it possible that my Qt implementation is broken? I tried the same using Qt5 at then it works perfectly fine. But with Qt4.8.1 it doesn't.

Comment: What is your declaration code ?

Comment: @Ilya What do you mean?

Comment: your headers, where you declare the classes

Comment: @Ilya I updated the question.

Comment: OK, thanks. What is you environnement (OS, compiler; Qt) ?

Comment: @Ilya Win7, VS2013, Qt 4.8.1

Comment: Qt 4.8.1 is **old** (4 years ?), lots of bug fixes from 4.8.1 to 4.8.7, and did you build it yourself, or is it pre-built ?

Comment: Make sure the Qt dlls that you are using were built with Visual Studio 2013 so you do not have multiple CRT implementations and multiple heaps.

Comment: Yes exactly, if it's pre-built it has to match your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see obvious problems with your code. If you're using C++11 in your code and an old Qt lib, you could try to upgrade to Qt 4.8.7 or Qt 5.x.

Answer (score 0):

Signal slot connection between threads are queued and not direct by default. I think because of while(1){} this problem is coming. Try giving sleep inside infinite loop so that event loop get processed.

Answer (score -1):

Try to make this changes. Connection:

```
connect(reader, SIGNAL(error(QString*)), this, SLOT(threadError(QString*)));
```

Emiting signal:

```
emit error(new QString("No new data for 500 samples"));
```

Slot:

```
void MainWindow::threadError(QString* msg) {
    std::string st = msg->toStdString();
    delete msg;
    int i = 0;
    .........
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Unfortunately the same problem occurs.

Comment: Then add breakpoint at begining of slot and look on `msg` and on `this`. Maybe your object is deleted when slot fires.

Comment: Ah, I look at you second question and found that you use `try...catch`. Never do this with Qt. Just try emit your signal without catch and see what happen.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing right now. That's why I posted another question. Yesterday I though it has something to do with the try catch and the deletion of the thread. But today I tried it outside of it, and the same error occurs..thanks for looking at it anyways.

Comment: could you point me in the direction of a source that explains why I shouldn't use try catch and emit? How else am I going to know when an exception has been thrown?

Comment: Then pleas edit your question and add more code you use.

Comment: right now for debugging purposes the Thread only emits the signal and enters an infinite loop. I updated the code